# Help with displaying views with EVA

Tags: views

I am struggling with displaying a view in a node. I have installed EVA module and have created a view of products categorized for that node (Restaurant Type).

The entity displays in the node but I'm having trouble contextualizing the view. How do I dynamically provide the context when the page containing the entity is viewed.

I am normally a PHP programmer and a newbie recently thrown into the Drupal framework. I have been able to print out the criteria (in php template) and display the entity but I am failing in making them play together.

I presume that the "Criteria" I am able to pry out of the template is the long way round solution to my issue, how do I configure my "entity view attachment" to display a contextualized list. my file structure always contains the variable and resolves as "***.com/restaurants/steak_houses" where "restaurants" is the node and "steak_houses" is the context criteria.

I need help in feeding that data to the entity.

Comment: I am set up in the same way as your example to no success. I think I am getting my context wrong, let me try to explain the parameters.

I have an a product list "Broilers" (it is a node) that in categorized according to the restaurant type "Restaurants" (Also a node). I am listing categorized broilers in the restaurants node (Restaurant type examples steak_houses, Institutional, fast_food etc).

when accessing the restaurant types the URL cites *.com/restaurants/steak_houses (the last phrase specifies the context "steak_houses".

Comment: Fields
Content: Thumbnail (Thumbnail)
Content: Title
Content: Broiler Category (Broiler Category)
Content: Description (Description)

Entity content settings
Entity type: Node
Bundles: Restaurant
Arguments: id
Show title: No
Access: Permission | View published content

Contextual filters
Content: Broiler Category 

-----------In the Context------------
I am able to set the context statically and get a proper list, unfortunately I am still unable to get the context to set dynamically.

Answer (score 12):

== Updated. Rewrite the answer, provide step by step screenshot ==

P.S. you also need [References](http://drupal.org/project/references), I apologize that didn't mention it.

1. Create a Content Type called Restaurant, everything by default, save. 
   [image]
2. Create a Content Type called Product
   [image]

   Add Node Reference field for Product Content Type. 
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]

Create an instance of Restaurant content.
[image]

Create an instance of Product content, set the node reference field to the resturant just created. 
[image]
[image]

Next, create a new EVA view. 
[image]
[image]

Add filter => Content type => Product
[image]

Set Entity to node, Bundle to Restaurant
[image] 
[image]

Add Contextual filter, select the node reference field created.
[image]

Provide default value => Content ID from URL
[image]

So you overall EVA view set up should be something like this:
[image]

Next, an important step: clear the cache, then refresh the restaurant node page to see the change:

[image]

You can see the Product One has been attached to the Restaurant.

You will get it. :)

Comment: I am set up in the same way as your example to no success. I think I am getting my context wrong, let me try to explain the parameters.

Comment: Can you show your content types setup and views setup? Screenshot would be great.

Comment: I assume that you have two content types for this. One is Product. One is Resturant. You want to attach a list of products nodes that associated with a resturant node TO that resturant node.   Right?

Comment: Yes, "restaurants" and "broilers". A list of broilers matching the restaurant category (steak_houses, amusement_parks, etc.)

Comment: For some reason the link ref on the edit isn't changing but the images can be downloaded from the links listed above

Comment: http://glenbass.net/test/images/entity_config.gif
http://glenbass.net/test/images/context.gif

Comment: I reset the context. I am concerned that I am not applying the correct bundle and when I set up the context its just not displaying dynamically

Comment: Hi gilzero:
I copied my config images to the following links
http://glenbass.net/test/images/entity-02.gif
http://glenbass.net/test/images/entity-arg-02

Comment: I think you understand the flow of data, do I have the bundle set correctly?

Comment: do I have to set the context criteria and could you show me how you set up yours? Thanks for all your help

Comment: I am able to search contextually and get a result in my preview. Context, Config and Preview Below:
http://glenbass.net/test/images/entity-03.gif
http://glenbass.net/test/images/entity-con-03.gif
http://glenbass.net/test/images/entity-prev-03.gif

Comment: Still no dynamic context on node view

Comment: I updated my answer, attached the screenshot of default argument value. You should get it.

Comment: I made the changes seen in your example--
http://glenbass.net/test/images/entity-con-04.gif
Still the same result, do I need to change anything under "When the filter value IS available or a default is provided".
Up to this point I have done the same as you, what could I be doing wrong?
ARGH!

Comment: I will create step by step screenshot for you. bear with me

Comment: My answer updated, try it. good luck.

Comment: I am trying it now. Thank you for all your support