# Views: display entity reference fields as view fields

Tags: views, entities

I have a content type (1) with an entity reference field that point to another content type (2).

I'm trying to create a view where I want to display fields of content type 1 mixed with the FIELDS of the content type 2.

When I go to add fields in my view I can see the fields of content type 2 but the output is empty, the only thing I can do is display the rendered content type 2 with all of its fields.

Is there a way to output single fields of content type 2 as view fields?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it. The [Entity view Attachment](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva)  module is built for such task. Using this module, fields of another content types becomes a filed of another one. this [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18440/help-with-displaying-views-with-eva) is a good tutorial of this module.